# What to do if updating Ubuntu would make it uncompatible with the system?

Tags: updates

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I need an update. I intentionally installed an outdated version of Ubuntu as 16.04 seemed to be the newest one that fit my computer.

My computer is 64 bit, has 2 GB memory, 30 GB storage, dual core, maximum 2.16 mega hertz processor and is really bad. I've checked the spec requirements and it seems that the newer versions don't fit. I care a lot about performance as my computer can barely run VS Code and Firefox together right now with 16.04 and forget about games. The RAM requirement is really really tight.

So, what do I do? I'll probably use some lighter Linux like some flavour of Ubuntu if there's no solution to this. I'm wondering if there's a way to like install the necessary bits of the newer OS and leave the rest or something crazy like that. Probably not, but asking advice won't hurt.

And by the way, I'm not asking for recommendations for which Ubuntu flavour to use or something like that. I'm just asking what to do, which is kind of a recommendation and is probably in the grey area of being on or off topic but should be an okay question.

I wonder how I used to use Windows 10(it was default in my PC) back in the day... ah.

Comment: You can and should use an Ubuntu derivative with a light desktop environment like Xubuntu or Lubuntu. OTOH, using an unsupported release is NEVER the answer.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed, either because you've tagged an EOL version, or because it's a "recommendation" question.  Have you checked the hardware requirements for other flavors of Ubuntu (Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.)?  Looked at other distributions specifically aimed at older/low-spec computers?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I know, it'll probably close. It's a fine question if I word it differently. People will probably see this as asking for recommendation for which flavour of Ubuntu to use, which is not the case. I'm just asking what to do, which is kind of a recommendation  but should be fine for the site. And yes, I have looked at those. I'm just asking this question to find out weather there is a way to still use Ubuntu.

Comment: @24601 No, that question asks for a good Ubuntu derivative, this one is just a general what to do.

Comment: If you want help from AskUbuntu you need to use an actively supported Ubuntu. 16.04 lacks security updates and should not be used to go online. Please install a derivative if speed is an issue but do install 21.04 or 21.10 :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Or 20.04 if you don't like being on the cutting edge.  I prefer LTS for my own use.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam You probably can't "upgrade" from 16.04 to a current version anyway, so I'd start by clean installing Lubuntu 20.04 or Xubuntu 20.04.  Or 18.04 only if the requirements went up between those (18.04 has 2 years to go on fully supported flavors, may be EOL for Lubuntu or Xubuntu).

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed itself End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @waltinator Yes but this is not a question about Ubuntu 16.04, this is about updating problem.

Comment: Then tag the version you're trying to update *to* as that's where the minimum hardware issue lies.  Might also mention if it's a laptop or desktop, and whether there's the possibility to install additional RAM (as that's the big bottleneck here).

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: I don't know why Ubuntu 16.04 LTS would be the newest to fit your computer... I used devices as old as from 2003 for QA-testing Ubuntu *flavors* up to 19.04; last used for [18.04.5](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/)  re-spins in 2020-August which included pentium M, pentium D, pentium 4 etc. If your machine is 64-bit it won't have that limit & can use later (I use c2d's with 2GB RAM to test *jammy* or what will be 22.04 when it's released). Recommendations belong though on Ubuntu Forums (as rely on *opinions* that don't belong on Q&A sites like this).